# Delete user directly from html template

Tags: python, django

I want to create a management page where an admin can delete users. I have succesfully made it list created users, but now i'm struggeling with how to create a deleteView to delete the user entirely from my django project.

Views.py

```
def index(request):
    users = User.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'EditUser.html',{'userlist':users})


def deletefunction(request,User =None):
    object = User.objects.get(id=User)
    object.delete()
    return render(request,'EditUser.html')
```

Project urls.py

```
from edit_user.views import deletefunction

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('management', include('management.urls')),
    path('management/create', include('signup.urls')),
    path('management/edit', include('edit_user.urls')),
    path('^delete/(?P<User>[0-9]+)/$', deletefunction, name='delete_view'),
]
```

HTML code

```
<div class="container">
          {% for item in userlist %} 
          <tr> 
              <td>{{ item.username }}</td><a href="{% url 'EditUser:deletefunction' User %}">delete</a> 
          </tr>  
          {% endfor %} 

          </div>
```

As of right now when i'm trying to load my page i'm receiving this exception.

> Reverse for 'deletefunction' not found. 'deletefunction' is not a
>   valid view function or pattern name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def deletefunction(request, user_id):
    object = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
    object.delete()
    users = User.objects.all()
    return render(request,'EditUser.html', {'userlist': users})
```

and

```
<div class="container">
          {% for item in userlist %} 
          <tr> 
              <td>{{ item.username }}</td><a href="{% url 'delete_view' item.id %}">delete</a> 
          </tr>  
          {% endfor %} 

          </div>
```

Comment: When I click the delete button im receiving this error

Comment: deletefunction() got an unexpected keyword argument 'User'

Comment: @LesnieSncheider did you change the function signature according to my edits?

Comment: Yes, I replaced all of my current code with yours. @py_dude

Comment: Can you change url like this  path('^delete/(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)/$', deletefunction, name='delete_view'),

Comment: @UtkucanBıyıklı That fixed it! Thanks! Seems like it's deleting the users now. They're dissapearing after I click delete now. How do I redirect back to my EditUser.html again instead of having the 127.0.0.1:8000/delete/stuff at my current link?

Comment: @LesnieSncheider `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('your-cool-view-name'))` or `return HttpResponseRedirect(url)`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should delete EditUser in href. Because you url in project urls.py(not EditUser urls ). So django looks EditUser app_name but they cant find.
Also you had not determineted 'User'.And you url name "delete_view" but you send view name.
Can you change like this?Maybe work.

```
<td>{{ item.username }}</td><a href="{% url 'delete_view' item.id %}">delete</a>
```